# What's the difference between "marketable" vs. "tradable" (tradeable)?

Tags: terminology, financial-literacy

In [Bodie's textbook "Investments"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073530700):

> Money market instruments include short-term, **marketable**, liquid,
>   low-risk debt securities.

I was wondering about the differences and relations between "marketable" and "tradable." Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a source for the term "tradable security"?  There are different possible definitions for that term.  A source might help answer your question.

Comment: No, I don't. What sources are there? By tradable, I mean for things that can be traded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tradable* is a much broader term than marketable.  For example, some programmers/developers sell their services online, hence programming is a *tradable* service.  However, it is not a *security* nor is it *marketable* since it cannot readily be converted to cash.  All marketable securities are, by definition, *tradable*.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder what "readily be converted to cash" means?

Comment: @Tim it means that you go to the market and ask for cash in exchange and you get it within a few days, no questions asked.